Differentiation of the Vandermonde determinant
Prove that the operator $$D=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2},$$
annihilates the Vandermonde determinant.
$$
V_n= \begin{vmatrix} x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\  x_1^{n-2} & x_2^{n-2} & \ldots & x_n^{n-2} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
x_1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Unfortunately, the operator $D$ is not a differentiation, and I cannot apply it to each row at a time, keeping other rows unchanged.
By sequentially performing differentiation, I have got that the sum of $n$ determinants
$$
D(V_n)=\begin{vmatrix} (n-1)(n-2)x_1^{n-3} & x_2^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\ (n-2)(n-3) x_1^{n-4} & x_2^{n-2} & \ldots & x_n^{n-2} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
2 & x_2^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\
0 & x_2 & \ldots & x_n \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 1
\end{vmatrix}+\cdots+\begin{vmatrix} x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \ldots &  (n-1)(n-2)x_n^{n-1} \\  x_1^{n-4} & x_2^{n-2} & \ldots & (n-2)(n-3)x_n^{n-2} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & \ldots & 2 \\
x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \ldots & 0
\end{vmatrix}
$$
But I do not yet see how to form a zero from this.
Is there another way to prove it?

“High level answers” on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/362849/116247

@ Martin R Thank you. I hope there is a low level answer

I'll use the Vandermonde determinant in the form
$$
V(x) = \begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
 x_1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
 x_1^{n-2} & x_2^{n-2} & \ldots & x_n^{n-2} \\ 
 x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} 
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. This differs from your definition at most by a factor $(-1)$.
It is well known that
$$
V(x) = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (x_j - x_i) \, .
$$
The first part of the following computation is essentially what Shannon Starr wrote on MathOverflow, and also what heropup wrote in their answer.
Using the logarithmic derivative we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} V(x) =
\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq k}}^n \frac{ V(x)}{x_k - x_i} \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2} V(x) =
\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq k}}^n \left( \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ i\neq k}}^n \frac{ V(x)}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)} 
- \frac{ V(x)}{(x_k - x_i)^2}\right)
= \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\ i\neq k, j \ne k, i \ne j}}^n \frac{ V(x)}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)} 
$$
and therefore
$$
D V(x) = V(x) \sum_{\substack{i,j, k=1\\ i\neq k, j \ne k, i \ne j}}^n \frac{ 1}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)} \, .
$$
This identity holds for all $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with pairwise distinct components $x_i$.
Now the second part: We show that
$$
 S(x) = \sum_{i, j, k}^n {\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{ 1}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)}
$$
is zero for all $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with pairwise distinct components $x_i$. Here I have used  $\sum_{i, j, k}^n {\vphantom{\sum}}'$ as an abbreviation for the sum over all pairwise distinct $(i, j, k)$.
With a partial fraction decomposition one gets
$$ 
S(x) = \sum_{i, j, k}^n {\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}\left( \frac{ 1}{x_k - x_i}- \frac{ 1}{x_k - x_j}\right) \\
= -\sum_{i, j, k}^n {\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{ 1}{(x_i - x_j)(x_i - x_k)}
 -\sum_{i, j, k}^n {\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{ 1}{(x_j - x_i)(x_j - x_k)} \, .
$$
The two sums on the right are both equal to $S(x)$ (only the indexing is different), i.e.
$$
 S(x) = -2 S(x) \implies S(x) = 0 \, .
$$
It follows that $DV(x) = 0$ (first for distinct $x_i$, and then for arbitrary arguments because of continuity). This concludes the proof.

Disclaimer.  I thought about this problem for a little while and although I got somewhere with it, I wasn't able to finish.  So what I have is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment and I didn't want to let it languish, in case someone else might be able to finish it off.  I decided to post now because there hasn't been any other responses.  I hope it's helpful to someone.

I would use the fact that $$V_n = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (x_j - x_i), \tag{1}$$
and employ logarithmic differentiation:
$$\log V_n = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \log(x_j - x_i), \tag{2}$$
hence
$$\frac{\partial V_n}{\partial x_k} = V_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \log(x_j - x_i). \tag{3}$$
Since the only terms in the sum $(3)$ that are functions of $x_k$ are those of the form $\log(x_k - x_i)$ when $k > i$ or $\log(x_j - x_k)$ when $k < j$, we have
$$\frac{\partial V_n}{\partial x_k} = V_n \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{x_k - x_i} - \sum_{j=k+1}^n \frac{1}{x_j - x_k}\right) = V_n \sum_{i \ne k} \frac{1}{x_k - x_i}. \tag{4}$$
This suggests letting $g(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i \ne k} \frac{1}{x_k - x_i}$.  Then the second derivative is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 V_n}{\partial x_k^2} 
&= \frac{\partial V_n}{\partial x_k} g + V_n \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k} \\
&= V_n g^2 - V_n \sum_{i \ne k} \frac{1}{(x_k-x_i)^2} \\
&= V_n \left( \left(\sum_{i \ne k} \frac{1}{x_k - x_i}\right)^2 - \sum_{i \ne k} \frac{1}{(x_k - x_i)^2} \right) \\
&= V_n \sum_{i \ne j \ne k} \frac{1}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)} 
\tag{5} \end{align}$$
where the last sum in $(5)$ is taken over all ordered pairs $(i,j)$ for which $i \ne j$, $i \ne k$, and $j \ne k$.  Consequently
$$\begin{align}
D(V_n) &=  V_n \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i \ne j \ne k} \frac{1}{(x_k - x_i)(x_k - x_j)} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
and since $V_n \ne 0$, the sum in $(6)$ must somehow be zero.  Unfortunately, this is where I stopped making progress.  Looking at some of the small $n$ cases shows that the result is true, but I haven't had time to press on with it.  I also get the vague impression that there's probably some clever theorem or result that could prove everything in a line or two, but this subject isn't in my area of expertise.

One way to prove this is by induction on dimension; this proof method may be simpler if applied to $V = \prod_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)$, but I have kept matrices in the proof to more closely address the question.
Let $V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be the $n$-dimensional Vandermonde determinant in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Then by Laplace's expansion along the first row, we have that:
$$V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n+1}x_i^{n-1} V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)$$
where $\widehat{(-)}$ denotes exclusion. We can now proceed with the induction; the bases cases are $n=1$ and $n=2$, both of which can be verified directly, so now let $n \geq 3$, and suppose that $\Delta' V_{n-1} = 0$, where $\Delta'$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional Laplacian in the appropriate variables. Now we can apply the Laplace expansion:
$$\Delta V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n+1} \Delta \left(x_i^{n-1} V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\right)$$
For each $i$, we have that:
\begin{align}\Delta \left(x_i^{n-1} V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\right) &= \partial_i^2 \left(x_{i}^{n-1}V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\right) \\ &\hphantom{123} + \Delta'\left(x_{i}^{n-1}V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\right) \end{align}
By induction, it follows that the last term vanishes, so we have:
\begin{align}\Delta V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n+1} \partial_{x_i}^2 \left(x_i^{n-1} V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n+1} (n-1)(n-2)x_i^{n-3} V_{n-1}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_i},\dots,x_n)\end{align}
But this is the determinant of the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} (n-1)(n-2)x_1^{n-3} & (n-1)(n-2)x_i^{n-3} & \cdots & (n-1)(n-2)x_n^{n-3} \\ x_1^{n-2} & x_2^{n-2} & \cdots &x_n^{n-2} \\ x_1^{n-3} & x_2^{n-3} & \cdots & x_n^{n-3} \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
which is evidently row-reducible to a matrix whose first row is all zeroes. Thus $\Delta V_n = 0$.
